# Join with 3 tables linked as parent child

Tags: oracle

I have a parent table

M_TRD
sk_trd
trd_name
trd_date

C_sub
sk_trd
subid
subname

C_subdet
sk_trd
subid
subdetid
subdet_name

Now, I need to retrieve all the trade details, sub details and sub details in a single query
There is one to many relationship between 
M_TRD and C_sub
one to many relationship from
C_sub to s_subdet

I need to use left join but not sure exactly how, I am new to sql.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM M_TRD trd
LEFT OUTER JOIN C_sub    sub ON trd.sk_trd = sub.sk_trd 
LEFT OUTER JOIN C_subdet det ON sub.subid  = det.subid
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM M_TRD LEFT LOIN C_sub ON M_TRD.sk_trd = C_sum.sk_trd LEFT JOIN C_subdet ON C_sub.sk_trd;

Comment: @kmas beat me to it, basically the same answer, kmas is prettier though :-)